# Problems with Strings in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

OK, so, I'm trying to make it if a read-only textbox1 equals some string, then another read-only textbox2 equals some other string, depending on what textbox1 is. For example, it textbox 1 is equal to "Hey" Textbox2 will be equal to "Hi". Here's what I have:

```
string responseString = "Hey";
if(TextBox1.Text == ("Hi"))
{
    TextBox2.Text = responseString;
}
```

I'm using Visual studios C# Express 2010. I'm new to this so I'm sorry for any dumb questions. My C# class hasn't gone into too much depth with `String`s and loops yet. Thanks!

I'm not getting any errors by the way, it just doesn't work.

Comment: What event have you placed your code in?

Comment: You have the strings other way around.

Comment: What do you mean *view only* textboxes? Do you actually mean *readonly*?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry. I meant read-only. I had it under:
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: When you say "view only textbox1", I think `Label`.

Comment: If your textboxes are readonly, how do you think their text will change so the event is fired?

Comment: I got it working. Code was under wrong event.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is currently backwards from what you've described you're trying to do:

```
string responseString = "Hi";

if (TextBox1.Text == "Hey")
{
    TextBox2.Text = responseString;
}
```

Comment: I figured it out. I had my code under the wrong event as Ahbi had said. I had in under the wrong textbox event.

Comment: @brettsalyer: In that case, the usual answer is to submit your own answer and accept it if you feel that this would be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string responseString = "Hi";
    if (TextBox1.Text == ("Hey"))
    {
        TextBox2.Text = responseString;
    }
}
```

Above is correct. I had it under the: `

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

which was not correct.`